# knockout validation tutorials

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

I am working with knockout and now i have to work on validation so that
 i choose `knockout-validation` . But as far as i searched on Google ,
i didn't find any tutorial about which i can say that its good
and in fact the problem is that there is not so good [documentation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) of `knockout-validation` .

I am facing many problems in knockout-validation , like

```
Implementing conditional validation etc etc.
```

Any body have link to a good tutorial .

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the world of open source :D That said, have you checked the wiki pages over at Github?

Comment: Yes , but thats also not enough when you are going to implement i a big project where there are thousands of different scenarios .

Comment: one problem yesterday i faced , i want to validate a observable only when there is a specific value is selected in dropdown and it almost took my 8 hours :-(

Comment: and there are so many other conditions

Comment: Can you provide some sample code and what kind of validation you are hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is your only friend here im afraid, but funny you took conditional validation as an example since that is in the docs :D

https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Conditional-Validation

Quick example 
http://jsfiddle.net/Va2yw/

```
ViewModel = function() {
    this.validate = ko.observable(true);
    this.required = ko.observable().extend({ required: { onlyIf: this.validate } });
};
```

Comment: i know its in docs , i just talked about it as a example